# Rails order active record by foreign attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have those queries:

```
@collections = Collection.all()
render :json => @collections.as_json(
              :include => :items
            )
```

and

```
@collection = Collection.find(params[:id])
```

For LIST and GET methods. And a Collection has zero or many Items.
I defined the relationship with belong_to field in Items and has_many field in Collection and that's working fine.

Then when I query the collections and render the JSON I would like to sort the items by an integer variable called number which belongs to Item.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
@collections = Collection.sort_by &:item_number
```

I want to sort the list of Item which is inside the Collection by number. This is what @collections = Collection.all() returns, and I would like to sort the list of Items by number.

> {"id":1,"title":"Collection","plot":"arrow","created_at":"2016-04-11T17:53:38.892Z","updated_at":"2016-04-11T17:53:38.892Z",
>   "item":[{"id":10,"title":"Item
>   12","collection_id":1,"created_at":"2016-04-11T23:27:08.302Z","updated_at":"2016-04-11T23:27:08.302Z","number":12},{"id":11,"title":"Item
>   102","collection_id":1,"created_at":"s2016-04-11T23:27:24.649Z","updated_at":"2016-04-11T23:27:24.649Z","number":10},{"id":12,"title":"Item
>   9","collection_id":1,"created_at":"2016-04-11T23:27:53.201Z","updated_at":"2016-04-11T23:27:53.201Z","number":9}]}

Comment: You would like to sort by sum of integers of by what? Get the instance, please, what are you really want

Comment: Hello! I have a list of Items inside Collection, I want to sort the Items which are inside the Collection by number

Comment: So you want to query your collections and receive them with sorted items ? What are the items ? A different model backed by a different table ? If that is the case, `Collection.all` should return you your collections without the corresponding items

Comment: I updated how I am rendering the collections, I include the items and I want those items get sorted by a item's field called number.

Comment: I want to order them from ascendent order, from smaller to greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `order` to your `has_many` relation in the `Collection` model

```
has_many :items, -> { order(:number) }
```

That will give you the list of items inside the collection sorted by number

Comment: Do I have to specify ASC or DESC?

Comment: it's ASC by default you can set `order(number: :asc)`

Comment: Would I have to generate a migration?

Comment: Ahh, that's working, thanks, that's what I needed, sorry I couldnt explain it clearer I am learning RoR